# How to carry logical function using 'menu' function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

For the case as stated below,

```
a=3; b=4; c=5;
k = menu ('choose','a','b','c');
```

If the user select `a` how can I assign a value for it and do a logical loop? For example,

```
if 'a'; x=a;
else if 'b'; x=b;
else if 'c'; x=c;
end
```

Then I can continue my calculation using the value of x assigned. For example,

```
w=x+5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k` is the number of the user's choice. In your case:

```
switch (k) 
    case 1
       x = a;
    case 2
       x = b;
    case 3
       x = c;
    otherwise
       fprintf(1, 'do not know what to do - user closed menu w/o selection\n');
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the returned output value `k` as follows:

```
if k == 1; x=a;
else if k == 2; x=b;
else x=c;
end
```

`k` is the integer showing the index of the button in your menu.

But instead I would do something as below:

```
values = [3 4 5];
k = menu('choose','a','b','c');
if k > 0
   x = values(k);
else
   error('You should provide an option.')
```